# bootstrap datepicker localization doesn't change

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap datepicker and I wanna change its language but I can not change its language even I  used Jquery $.fn.setDefault function and I got 'Can not read propert' by the way I added bootstrap localazition script.Even I used language property and again result same.Thanks for help.

Comment: Maybe something is wrong in your code or logic, who knows?...

Comment: It would be better to put the code that you are using

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap datepicker download package supplies js files for localization which you can find under `js/locales`. For example if you want to change the language to Spanish then you will have to include the file `<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.es.js"></script>` after including the main js file of boostrap datepicker. So what you have to do is:

```
 <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.es.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){ 

    $('#dpd1').datepicker({
    ......
    ......
    language:'es'
    });
});
```

For further reference on localization please refer the link : http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/i18n.html

Answer (score 0):

Now I took this error 'Cannot set property 'tr' of undefined ' , I am using 'tr' localization .Same you said to me like I am done.it has never changed.